# How To Send FormData object?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

1. get Form with id
2. create formdata with Form ID
3. send Data with $.ajax

My code:

```
<form id="company">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="tel" name="tel" />
    <input type="button" id="send" name="send" value="send" />
</form>


 <script>
        ##get Form id an create form data##
        var testForm = document.getElementById('send');
        testForm.onclick = function(event) {
            var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('company'));
        ##this is Ajax Method##
                $.ajax({
                    url : './json/company.php',
                    method : 'POST',
                    data : formData,
                    timeout : 10,
                    dataType :'json',
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        alert("Success");
                    }
                });
        }
    </script>
```

> Error : TypeError: Argument 1 of FormData.constructor is not an object

Comment: why do you use a formData object?

Comment: There's another way?

Comment: see my answer for that

Comment: This is already discussed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery

Comment: Depends on what you're sending, if you intend to send files or other binary data, `formData` is the way to go, if you're just sending text, you could serialize the form, but `formData` would still be fine *(unless you have to support old browsers)*

Comment: @RAHULROY this form doesn't have a input type file so he doesn't need a formData object

Comment: means if Form have File Input must user formData  else must do another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your form doesn't have a input type file you should use the [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function instead

```
$(testForm).click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();//don't forget to prevent the default click event from redirecting you from the page
                $.ajax({
                    url : './json/company.php',
                    method : 'POST',
                    data : $('#company').serialize(),
                    timeout : 10,
                    dataType :'json',
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        alert("Success");
                    }
                });
        });
```

Comment: tnx,i do it but Not Send parameters ,Fire Fox NetWork Mode Say "No Parameters for this request"

Comment: can you post a screenshot of that message?

Comment: are you sure that the id of the form is `#company` and is unique?

Comment: Yes i'm sure, a quest if my form with diffrent name in another form with diffrent name have problem?

Comment: you have a form in a form? how will you submit the inner form ?? the submit button will trigger the  outer form

Comment: ooops understand , so tnx for help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data : JSON.stringify(formData)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing crucial options, and jQuery is trying to process the formData, which it can't.
You have to add the `processData: false` option, and you should avoid sending a contentType as well

```
var testForm = document.getElementById('send');
testForm.onclick = function(event) {
    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('company'));
    $.ajax({
        url: './json/company.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        timeout: 10,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Success");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use formdata with jquery you have to set the correct options

```
var testForm = document.getElementById('send');
testForm.onclick = function(event) {
    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('company'));
    $.ajax({
        url : './json/company.php',
        type: "POST",
        data : formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
          alert("Success");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            //if fails     
        }
    });
}
```